# how to fix NoClassDefFoundError in eclipse or netBeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

hello everybody I write my java project with eclipse and run in eclipse too but I got error, this is my code:

```
package first;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;
import java.io.*;
//import com.hp.hpl.jena.
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Zara-t
 */
public class First {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("hi");
        First test=new First();
        test.start();
    }
    private Model model;

    public void start(){
        String file = "D:\\arshad-comp\\terme2\\expertSys\\food.owl";
         // create an empty model
         Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

         // use the FileManager to find the input file
         InputStream in = FileManager.get().open( file );
        if (in == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                         "File: " + file + " not found");
        }

        // read the RDF/XML file
        model.read(in, null);

        // write it to standard out
        model.write(System.out);
    }
}
```

my project is in c:\wamp\www\projectFolder and my library that I added to my project is in this path D:\arshad-comp\terme2\expertSys\protege-5.0.0-beta-15\Protege_5.0_beta\test\bin and this is my classpath content

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/arshad-comp/terme2/expertSys/protege-5.0.0-beta-15/Protege_5.0_beta/jena.zip"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

and this is the error lines:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.PropertyImpl.<clinit>(PropertyImpl.java:61)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.BuiltinPersonalities.<clinit>(BuiltinPersonalities.java:27)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.<init>(ModelCom.java:51)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:125)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:119)
    at first.First.start(First.java:35)
    at first.First.main(First.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 7 more
Java Result: 1
```

I don't know really what to do :( I can't remember what changed I made. mycode works 1day ago I do any solution in the internet 
help me please

Comment: Which **logger API** are you using , exception indicates log API's jar not found ?

Comment: Probably should get http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/

Comment: I don't your mean by which logger API.  I just add jena to my project libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jena needs that LogFactory class at runtime,you can see the dependency to logging library [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/hp/hpl/jena/jena/2.6.4/jena-2.6.4.pom) in jena pom, adding a logging utility library will fix that.Class: LogFactory is in commons-logging you can download it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1)

Comment: i download log4j and add it my project as a external jar (is this true?) but when I run project again same errors show

Comment: for complete guide beginner like me can use this link too :) 
http://www.iandickinson.me.uk/articles/jena-eclipse-helloworld/